# Android MediaPlayer short audio makes problems

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, httpconnection

I use a MediaPlayer to stream an audio webM file from the web. If the audio is longer than ~10 seconds there are no problems: the player starts and executes all methods in the correct row.

But if I want to stream an audio file which is < ~10 seconds, it executes in the same row, but needs up to 20 seconds to start playing the file.

```
mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        if (mp.getDuration() > 0) {
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
            seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
            updateProgressBar();
            setButtonVisibility(View.INVISIBLE, View.VISIBLE, -1, View.GONE);
            mp.start();
        }
});
```

I got no erros but this info (seems the problem results in the 416 status?):

```
02-26 17:14:11.721 27281-27281/com.audiotube E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
02-26 17:14:11.801 27281-27292/com.audiotube I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
02-26 17:14:11.801 27281-27292/com.audiotube I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
02-26 17:14:11.841 27281-27292/com.audiotube I/MediaHTTPConnection: response code = 416
```

Whats the problem with short files and how can I fix it? How do I have to understand the 416 status code in this context?